# Is it possible to change the output width of PHP Shell_Exec?

Tags: php

I'm looking to parse the output that I'm getting back from PHP `shell_exec`. But some of the output that's returned is in tabular format and the data is wrapping within the columns as shown here...

```
Name                       Installed      Proposed  Message
                            Version        version
Views Bulk Operations      7.x-3.3        7.x-3.4   Update available
(views_bulk_operations)
Chaos tools (ctools)       7.x-1.12       7.x-1.13  Update available
CAS (cas)                  7.x-1.5        7.x-1.7   Update available
Custom Search              7.x-1.18       7.x-1.20  Update available
(custom_search)
Date iCal (date_ical)      7.x-3.5        7.x-3.9   Update available
Entity API (entity)        7.x-1.8        7.x-1.9   SECURITY UPDATE available
Field Group (field_group)  7.x-1.5        7.x-1.6   Update available
Media (media)              7.x-1.6        7.x-2.16  SECURITY UPDATE available
Insert (insert)            7.x-1.3        7.x-1.4   Update available
Views (views)              7.x-3.16       7.x-3.18  SECURITY UPDATE available
Views Data Export          7.x-3.0-beta8  7.x-3.2   SECURITY UPDATE available
(views_data_export)
Views PHP (views_php)      7.x-1.0-alpha  7.x-1.0-  Update available
                           1              alpha3
Athena (athena)            Unknown        Unknown   Project was not packaged
                                                    by drupal.org but
                                                    obtained from git. You
                                                    need to enable git_deploy
                                                    module
```

To make it easier to parse, I was hoping to be able to change the width of the output so the data doesn't wrap.

I assumed that specifying the width of the console with stty would work, but it doesn't. I tried this...

`$output = shell_exec('stty cols 180; cd /; cd ' . $drupal_sites_folder_path . $list_of_drupal_sites[22] . '; drush pm-updatestatus');`

...but the output width is still set to 80 cols.

Any suggestions on how to change the width of the output from `shell_exec`?

Comment: I'd check if the command you're running doesn't have a flag for disabling the output wrapping - it seems like the column-based output is formatted by the command/program itself rather than by shell/tty

Comment: Wouldn't it work to create a bash script that sets and exports the COLUMNS environment variable and then calls your executable program? You call said bash script with shell_exec().

Comment: I like that. Thanks. I'll give it a try.